# Is there a way to group rows by a term and insert this term as a header in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of books on Google Sheets that will be turned into a paged layout on [InDesign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_InDesign). Each book has two additional information besides its title (year and theme).
Like this

[image: Sample list of books]

But I need this list to be structured in a stacked way. Grouping first by year, and then by theme, like this (I've formatted the cells just to clarify):

[image: Stacked list]

I currently do this stacking manually, and it requires quite a lot of time. Is there some sort of formula, or tool, to solve this problem? I guess it can be done with scripting, but I wanted to know if there's a non-scripting way to do it before diving into Google sheets script documentation.

Answer (score 0):

## Formula

`=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",IF(A2:A10=A1:A9,,"Year "&A2:A10)&","&C2:C10&","&IF(B2:B10=B1:B9,,B2:B10)),",")))`

## Explanation

1. We could use a 2D references to make comparisons, i.e. `A2:A10=A1:A9`.
2. Using and empty argument for the value if true or value if false of `IF` returns a blank.
3. `&` concatenates values and functions results. We are using a comma as separator between IF results and the values of `C2:C10`.
4. `JOIN` joins the values of a `1 x n` or `n x 1` range. We are using a comma as separator.
5. `SPLITS` separate subtext of a text. We are using a comma as subtext delimiter.
6. `ArrayFormula` expands the result of the inner formula to range of the required size by the result.